# open MATLAB figure in ubuntu

Tags: matlab, ubuntu

In windows, a `.fig` created by MATLAB can be easily opened. I am wondering if there is a way in ubuntu that allows you to open a .fig file through MATLAB. I guess i can open matlab then open there figures. But there shall be better ways.

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu Linux File Associations](http://linuxfud.wordpress.com/2006/09/03/ubuntu-linux-file-associations/) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16580/where-are-file-associations-stored) post on *askubuntu* might help on catching up with windows.

**EDIT:**
From within MATLAB use the menu 'FILE'->'Open', or the command line `open figname.fig`.

Comment: What does file associations have to do with the question?

Comment: @İsmail 'cartman' Dönmez: I'm referring to *But there shall be better ways.* part of the question. One better way I could think of is by clicking on the .fig file in a file explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like only Matlab opens it, a Google search reveals that although `*.fig`extension is usually associated with [`Xfig`](http://homepage.usask.ca/~ijm451/fig/) and related software but the Matlab's `fig`format seems to be a different, proprietary implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this thread might be old, but there might be some people that still need this... :) So:

The idea to solve this is to assign a custom command to the file type "*.fig", which is: `matlab -desktop -r "open(%f)"`, assuming that MATLAB is in your binaries.

If not then just make a symbolic link to it, like: `sudo ln -s /{MATLAB_BIN_LOCATION} /usr/bin/`

Under Ubuntu, if you cannot add a custom command like this: 
*Right click the .fig - file --> "Open with Other Application" --> Use a custom command --> matlab -desktop -r "open(%f)"*
one can use [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) for that.